# Pandas select rows where conditions meet across 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data frame i.

I want to select where both columns(QUANTITY and Net) in one row are not equal to 0..

i.e.

If I want rows where either column is 0 I would use...

```
wanted = i[(i.QUANTITY != 0) & (i.Net != 0)]
```

Instead I am looking where both QUANTITY and Net are not equal to zero in the same row, Not one or the other..Is there a work around for this??  Sorry I had to edit ... Had a typo earlier

Comment: The code you have displayed will select those rows where both of the specified columns have non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the inequalities `!=` into equalities `==`:

```
wanted = i.loc[(i.QUANTITY == 0) & (i.Net == 0)]
```